# Regex to exclude following character

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to use regex within GA to exclude a string that is followed by a -

My regex currently is /ask-a-question[^-] but this seems to exclude everything, not just what I'm looking for.

Hopefully that makes sense - if anyone is able to give me a steer on how I should use this I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exclude everything", examples would help. I guess that end of string position is not considered here, so, you may need `/ask-a-question([^-]|$)`

Comment: By exclude everything, I mean it wasn't showing any results at all.  Thanks for your suggestion, this seems to have done the trick.
Just for my understanding, this is basically saying return results that begin with /ask-a-question that is either not followed by a - or that contains anything or nothing after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[^-]` is a *consuming pattern and requires a character other than `-` after your string `/ask-a-question`. That means, this string won't get matched at the end of string.

Since RE2 does not support lookarounds, you should use an alternation group:

```
/ask-a-question([^-]|$)
               ^^^^^^^^
```

The `([^-]|$)` means: match either any char other than `-` (`[^-]`, negated character class) or (`|`) the end of string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string. 'ask-a-question' could be anything (`*`) that ends with `-`. For example:

```
^/*-$
```